# Get multiple tables from CSV and create many dataframes in Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, csv

I would like to extract several tables in a csv/excel file and put them into separate dataframes in Python. All the tables start in column B of the CSV and have the same number of rows, though the number of columns may change. For example, the tables in the CSV look like this (for ABC, XYZ, ....):

```
ABC                 
                                X
        2010    2011    2012    3 YEARS 
TITLE1  A       A       A       A       
TITLE2  B       B       B       B       
TITLE3  C       C       C       C       
TITLE4  D       D       D       D       
TITLE5  E       E       E       E       



XYZ                     
                                X
        2010    2011    2012    3 YEARS 
TITLE1  A       A       A       A       
TITLE2  B       B       B       B       
TITLE3  C       C       C       C       
TITLE4  D       D       D       D       
TITLE5  E       E       E       E
```

Some of the tables have additional columns like this:

```
DEF                     
                                                X
        2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    5 YEARS
TITLE1  A       A       A        A      A       A
TITLE2  B       B       B        B      B       B
TITLE3  C       C       C        C      C       C
TITLE4  D       D       D        D      D       D
TITLE5  E       E       E        E      E       E
```

Is there a way to extract tables ABC, XYZ, DEF,... and make them all their own separate dataframes in Python? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")

dataframes = []

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    # check if the row starts with 'Z'
    if df.iloc[i, 0].startswith("Z"):
        table_df = df.iloc[i:, :]
        table_df = table_df.iloc[1:, :]
        dataframes.append(table_df)

print(dataframes)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it out shortly! Regarding the `.startswith("Z"):` part, what if the table titles were to change? For example, if there is different title like `ABCD` instead of a title starting with `Z`, how would the code change then? I updated my question accordingly, sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I tried your code out, but the problem is that the dataframes are all combined in the list, and they are not in their own separate dataframes. Is there a way to keep them separate, even if it is inside a list object? In addition, the code actually replicates all the tables many many times :(